# How to sort the date and print the sorted data in unix?

Tags: sorting, date, unix, sed

I have a log file a follows and I want to sort the data in it and print the data between the specified startime and endtime.

```
Logfile:
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[11/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
[11/06/16 06:22:35  BST] Data 3
[12/06/16 06:22:35  BST] Data 3
[11/07/16 11:07:30  BST] Data 3
[12/08/16 09:08:07  BST] Data 4
[22/08/16 09:08:07  BST] Data 4
```

I am using the following command.

```
sort -n -k 1.5 -k 1.3 -k 1 logfile | sed -n "/[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST]/,/[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST]/p";
```

But it is displaying all the data in the file.But I want to stop it at the endtime which I mentioned. Is there a better way? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all, it does not sort correctly. And then you need to escape the square brackets in your `sed` command.

Comment: `sort -n -k 1.5 -k 1.3 -k 1 logfile` This command gives me the sorted output even if the input is not in sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the brackets and also the slashes in the date part. Try this (works on my laptop):

```
sort -n -k 1.5 -k 1.3 -k 1 logfile | sed -n "/\[10\/04\/16 02:07:20  BST\]/,/\[12\/05\/16 04:11:09  BST\]/p"
```

output:

```
[10/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1  
[11/04/16 02:07:20  BST] Data 1  
[10/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2  
[12/05/16 04:11:09  BST] Data 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Works fine.